# C# Entity Framework: overriding properties before saving to database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 and creating an API with a database that is used by a custom made ORM by my company years ago.

In this old ORM: in the GET Mapper, some values in the Database were acted on before mapping it to the correct property. For example, some datetime properties were changed to the user timezone and then when being saved to the database, the opposite mapper changed the user timezone datetime to UTC to save in the Database.

HOW could this be done in EF 6? help PLEASE!!! a place where I can write custom logic on CERTAIN properties...not all before reading and saving

Comment: What about in get and set for the property? EF saves what the getter returns and use the setter to set the property value ...

Answer (score 1):

What about using a partial class with properties that read/write from/to the database property?

```
public partial Entity
{
    public DateTime UseThisDate
    {
        get { return ToUserLocalTime(BackendDate); }
        set { BackendDate = ToUTC(value); }
    }
}
```

The `BackendDate` would be the column mapped to the database while `UseThisDate` would be the property you'd use in your logic layer.

Comment: nice, that would work, I'll probably create a template file to generate them since there are 600+ tables. FML